# How can I create a side menu from some menu subItems in the same page?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a horizontal menu, some of the Items have expandable subItems and all this is built with scripts that I do not have access to, I can only add and remove items through the dashboard and style and interact with the html templates (BigCommerce). I would like to reuse one of this menu Items and it's subItems as an additional side navigation.  Is there the possibility to do this with only javascript? When I explore the Menu with firebug the output has a similar scheme to this,

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li class="">Item1</li>
  <li class="hasSubMenu">Item2</li> 
   <ul>
    <li>SubItem1</li>
    <li>SubItem2</li>
    <li>SubItem3</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="">Item1</li>
  <li class="hasSubMenu">Item2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there no IDs for the `div`, `ul` etc.? Also by dynamically generated, do you mean when the page is generated or are items added dynamically after the page is loaded?

Comment: It is generated when the page is generated as a result of whatever the template variable is set to have from within the Dashboard of BC and as for the classes, ids, these are generic, like empty classes for the horizontal nav dropdown options that has no subpages and a class "hasSubPages" for the ones that show options. The left side menu would be made of only a particular option from that horizontal menu and have it's sub pages as a list on the side.

Answer (score 1):

As far I am concerned, you can edit the CSS and add custom templates on BC. If I got your point, the menu you have there is for the categories, right? To re-use it on the left navigation, you will need to go to the `Design > Template Files > Default.html` and find `%%Panel.SideCategoryList%%`. It will depend how you have your template layout, but it should be there. Once you find that Panel, go to your left navigation **[make sure you have one]** and add `%%Panel.SideCategoryList%%` there as well. You don't need to do nothing else. BC will adjust it automatically for you.

As you mentioned, you cannot interact will all the scripts, but you can "bypass" them, at least a good 79% of them.

Hope it solved your question.

**Ps:** I could not put it as a comment, so I am sorry if it is not what you are looking for, but let me know and I will do my best to rectify my answer.